# How to activate a QPainter::beginNativePainting , Painter inactive QGLWidget?

Tags: qt, qt5, qglwidget

I got a *.dll file with follwing class signature

```
class Render_WidgetGL: public QGLWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
}
```

I created such a Render_WidgetGL object and set that to a layout object

```
Render_WidgetGL* renderWidget = new Render_WidgetGL(resources);
QGridLayout* gridLayout = new QGridLayout;
gridLayout->addWidget(renderWidget, 0, 1);
ui->horizontalLayout_5->addLayout(gridLayout);
```

When I start and execute my application I got following message:

RenderProject|nderBackendOpenGlES2|Using GLEW 1.12.0
RenderProject|nderBackendOpenGlES2|OpenGL 2.0: 1
QPainter beginNativePainting: Painter not active
QPainter setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
QPainter beginNativePainting: Painter not active
QPainter beginNativePainting: Painter not active

I do not have such a Painter object in my code, so I assume it comes within the *.dll library. So how can I activate the Painter ?
(By the way: The Qt docssay, that QGlWidget is obsolete)

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Looks more like a bug in that DLL you're using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGLWidget has a [paintEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglwidget.html#paintEvent) which obviously uses those beginNativePainting functions - in your libraries (*.dll).

So you can replace in the *.dll beginNativePainting in that paintEvent Method:

```
void Render_Widget_GL::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event){
//.. do stuff 
painter.beginNativePainting();
// .. do stuff
painter.endNativePainting();
//.. do stuff
}
```

.. with ... :

```
void Render_Widget_GL::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event){
//.. do stuff 
painter.begin(this);
// .. do stuff
painter.end();
//.. do stuff
}
```